# Trying to create simple file transfer web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a very simple file transfer web service with ASP.NET

I found this tutorial online: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/create-a-simple-file-transfer-web-service-with-net/

and I did the following:

- Opened Visual Studio 2013
- Created a new ASP.NET Web Application
- Selected template Web Forms
- Added a new Web Form called 'FileRW.aspx'
- Opened FileRW.aspx.cs and pasted in the following code:

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://someplace.com/FileIO/")]
public class FileRW : WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public byte[] GetFile(string filename)
    {
        BinaryReader binReader = new
 BinaryReader(File.Open(Server.MapPath(filename), FileMode.Open,
 FileAccess.Read));
        binReader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
        byte[] binFile =
 binReader.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(binReader.BaseStream.Length));
        binReader.Close();
        return binFile;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public void PutFile(byte[] buffer, string filename)
    {
        BinaryWriter binWriter = new
 BinaryWriter(File.Open(Server.MapPath(filename), FileMode.CreateNew,
 FileAccess.ReadWrite));
        binWriter.Write(buffer);
        binWriter.Close();
    }
}
```

- Opened FileRW.aspx and pasted the following:

Code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="FileRW.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.FileRW" %>

<script runat="server">

    // Insert page code here
    //

    void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        string filename = "c:\\temp\\" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".tmp";
        file1.PostedFile.SaveAs(filename);
        System.IO.BinaryReader br = new
 System.IO.BinaryReader(System.IO.File.Open(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Open,
 System.IO.FileAccess.Read));
        FileIO.FileRW frw = new FileIO.FileRW();
        frw.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        br.BaseStream.Position = 0;
        Response.Write(br.BaseStream.Length);
        byte[] buffer = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(br.BaseStream.Length));
        br.Close();
        frw.PutFile(buffer,
file1.PostedFile.FileName.Substring(file1.PostedFile.FileName.LastIndexOf("\\")
+ 1));
    }

</script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server">
        <p>
            <input id="file1" type="file" name="file1" runat="server"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            &nbsp;<asp:Button id="Button1" onclick="Button1_Click"
 runat="server" Text="Button"></asp:Button>
        </p>
        <!— Insert content here —>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and after I paste the code into FileRW.aspx I get this error 'The type or namespace name 'FileIO' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?'

My question is what assembly am I missing ? or does anyone now of another tutorial on how to do a simple file transfer from a server, kinda like a FTP thing, list the files and open a file.

Comment: "FileIO" is probably the namespace for the web service.

Comment: Side note: Searching for tutorials is explicit off-topic for SO... just saying...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - OP is not asking for tutorials, they are asking for help on a tutorial, and I don't think that is OT for SO.

Comment: @Tim - sure... "does anyone now of another tutorial on how to do a simple file transfer from a server" is definitely not a part of the post (but I just put it as comment since there is some other question asking one to go through tutorial, check with tutorial author and figure out missing steps) .

Answer (score 0):

First for web service you need to create a .asmx file not .aspx file and after that you need to call that service in your application.after that run web service separately copy the url and use that url in your application like you working on web forms so click on reference and select "add service reference" one window will appear paste url there and click OK service will add in your application after that what you want to do.you can

Hope it will help for you
Thanks